# Yup validation for dynamic checkbox field

Tags: reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I am trying to add yup validation to my react-hook-form for a dynamically created checkbox array but can't seem to nail down the Yup validation part.

The functionality I'm looking to accomplish is the following: At least one checkbox out of the array must be checked to move forward. I assume this would be validated by the `is_active` key/value pair to determine if it is set to true?

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-dew-9un1c

**Current Yup Validation:**

```
const optionValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  options: Yup.array()
    .of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        is_active: Yup.boolean().oneOf([true]),
      })
    )
    .required('Must choose at least one option.'),
});
```

**Object returned on submit:**

```
"options":{
    "option1": {
        "id":"option1"
        "is_active": true
    }
    "option2": {
        "id":"option2"
        "is_active": false
    }
    ...
}
```

**Dynamically created checkbox array:**

```
{options.map((option) => {
    const optionKey = option.id;
    const name = `options[${optionKey}].is_active`;

    return (
        <Col lg={4} key={optionKey}>
            <div className={`onboard__label ${option.is_active ? "is-checked" : ""}`}>
                {option.name}
                <input
                  type="hidden"
                  name={`options[${optionKey}].id`}
                  defaultValue={optionKey}
                  ref={register}
                />
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  ref={register}
                  name={name}
                  defaultChecked={option.is_active}
                />
            </div>
        </Col>
    );
})}
```

**The error i'm currently getting:**
`options must be a 'array' type, but the final value was: 'null'`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `optionKey` as your array index. So you code will be evaluated to something like this

```js
<input name='options[option1]' />
<input name='options[option2]' />
<input name='options[option3]' />
```

But what you need to do is to assign `name[index]` where `index` is a number as demonstrated in the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api#register)

```js
<input name='options[0]' />
<input name='options[1]' />
<input name='options[2]' />
```

Also your schema should look like this instead

```js
Yup.object().shape({
   is_active: Yup.boolean(),
})
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63873063/yup-validation-for-dynamic-checkbox-field-react-hook-form]